# Помогите разобраться с функцией mail()

Tags: email, php, хостинг

Привет всем. У меня такой вопрос. Даже не знаю с чего начать. Короче у меня есть некий файлик (компромат)), который я отправил своему(своей) недоброжелателю по почте с помощь функции `mail()`. Сам запускающий почту файл находился на моем хостинге)) Теперь гражданин(ка) К. подал(а) на меня в милицию за распространение сего опасного документа, и я главный "подозреваемый". В субботу придут следователи и проверят мой компьютер, флешки и т.д. Я хотел бы узнать какова вероятность того, что меня вычислят и отправят на ишафот)) Почту я отправлял с подменой адреса отправителя. Адрес моего сайта они знают. Надеюсь на поддержку. Спасибо.

P.S. Основано на реальных событиях, все персонажи реальны.

P.P.S. Проголосуйте, если вам понравился мой вопрос)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

собственно чтобы не запалили, я бы такой вопрос не писал тут, ибо он уже возможно был проиндексирован поисковиками :)

А вообще откуда отправлено письмо узнать не сложно, подмена адреса какого? поле "от кого" ха, это смешно, менять в лучшем случае нужно IP адрес откуда, а не поле, так что вычислить лекго, особенно письмо у неё лежит на почте, а еще в России некоторые службы имеют право обратиться за помощью и предоставления информации, допустим к яндексу и он должен предоставить все заголовки принятого письма, ну а тут будет все понятно.
Сделал ты себе геморрой, смирись с этим.

Comment: @Shrek, вы имеете в виду надо было выходить через прокси? И насколько я понял, доказать что письмо отправлено с моего сайта не составит труда? Хотя сам запускаемый PHP-файл давно удален.

Comment: Ну нужно было, да, сейчас даже и не знаю что поможет. только ssh доступ к серваку и удаление всего чего возможно из логов.

Собственно @avp уже написал это.

Comment: @Shrek, что такое SSH доступ?

Comment: SSH-безопасная оболочка для удаленной работы на сервере. (в двух словах)

А логи удалить скорее всего не удастся, т.к. хостер вряд ли даст доступ к логам отправки почты. если другого не предусмотрено настройками на сервере.

Answer (score 0):

По IP и MessageId в заголовках почты можно найти отправителя, из логов MTA там найти uid процесса, вызвавшего mail.

Как привязать  uid к физическому лицу ? (ну, утюг, паяльник ...).

Comment: @avp, а можно как-нибудь очистить этот лог?

Comment: Естественно можно (при доступе к компьютеру и бэкапам).

Comment: @avp, а можно подробней. Что такое SSH и как поудалять все логи с сервера?

Comment: Судя по Вашим вопросам, **темный_мститель**, самый реальный способ решения проблемы - это начать с похода с их сисадмином в ресторан...

Comment: @avp молодцом!

Comment: @avp, неужели больше нет способов?

Comment: неа, нет. не ищи даже